# CodeIgniter - Best way for checking true result

Tags: php, codeigniter

What’s the best way for checking if some method in model or anywhere else was correctly carried out?

Is this a good way?

Model:

```
$data['field1'] = $this->input->post('field1');
$data['field2'] = $this->input->post('field2');
$data['field3'] = $this->input->post('field3');

if ($this->db->insert('table', $data))
{
   return TRUE;
}
else
{
   return FALSE;
}
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('page_view', $data);
}
else
{
    if ($this->Model->Insert_data())
    {
       $this->session->set_flashdata("insertsuccess", TRUE);
    }
    else
    {
       $this->session->set_flashdata("inserterror", TRUE);
    }
    $this->load->view('page_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just do `return $this->db->insert('table', $data);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with these

// INSERT

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

// UPDATE and DELETE

```
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

// SELECT

```
$this->db->num_rows();
```

Comment: How to use them then?
Model:
   `function my_insert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('table', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id(); 
    }`
Controller:
`if ($this->insert->my_insert($data) == TRUE)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata("insertsuccess", TRUE);
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata("inserterror", TRUE);
}`

Comment: model is the place where you do all the data manipulation stuff. so try these in models

Comment: This means that I have to get $this->input->post() in model instead of controller?

Comment: i mean when you are using active record in model here u can use