# How to know the number of rows deleted in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

How to know the no of deleted rows in codeigniter provided that `$this->db->affected_rows()` returns every time ie. on success or on fail also

Comment: Doc says it returns the number (and as I recall it does)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10488267/1239506

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to know the no of deleted rows in codeigniter provided that $this->db->affected_rows() returns every time ie. on success or on fail also

I don't use CodeIgniter, but normally, `affected_rows( )` should return the number of rows affected. That means, if the query succeeded, it should *always* be an integer. If 0 is returned, no rows are deleted, if > 0, that number is deleted.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->db->where($conditions)->delete('mytable');
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested it out, according to codeigniters website there is a hack that returns correct amount of rows, that's turned on by default.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Codeigniter userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html) it returns the correct number of rows:

> "Note: In MySQL "DELETE FROM TABLE" returns 0 affected rows. The
>   database class has a small hack that allows it to return the correct
>   number of affected rows. By default this hack is enabled but it can be
>   turned off in the database driver file."

so therefore this should work:

```
 $this->db->delete('1', 'your_table');
 echo ($this->db->affected_rows()." rows were deleted");
```

If it doesn't work, then just do this as a non-ideal workaround

```
$count = $this->db->count_all('your_table');
$this->db->delete('1', 'your_table');
$new_count = $this->db->count_all('your_table');
if ($new_count > $count)
{
    echo (($new_count-$count)." rows was deleted");
}
else
{
    echo "nothing deleted";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would help if you were more specific, with example...
But you can perform a SELECT COUNT(*) before deletion and after and compare the two results.