# affected_rows() in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Say I have a form which gets populated when clicked on some link and the user is allowed to update the data and save the changes made to those fields.

```
$data = array('somevalue, 'somevalue');            
$this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'))->update('links', $data);

            if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){
                return TRUE;
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }
```

And when I make some changes and do the save everything works fine because it returns `TRUE` for `affected_rows() == 1`. What if I dont make any changes and do the save? No any row is going to be affected and it will return `FALSE`.

What would be the appropriate way to solve this issue? The main problem is that I am displaying the success message only when it returns `TRUE`. So there will be a problem(i.e no message is displayed) if no changes are made and save button is clicked.

Comment: Try  if($this->db->affected_rows() > 1).

Comment: see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10488267/1239506

Comment: return (bool)$this->db->affected_rows();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return true.

If there is a problem with connecting to your DB you will get an error message before the application reaches that point anyway.

It is redundant code.

You should just be able to do

```
return $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'))->update('links', $data);
```

But you will need to check under which scenarios codeigniter return false.

P.S Cannot why not just use form validation in codeigniter to check if the fields are empty or not before going to the model?

Comment: I am not talking about the empty fields. The fields are prepopulated and if some changes are made and saved, it returns true. But if no changes are made i.e the preppulated values are left as they were and saved, it returns false.